# RCurl: Traverse Remote Directory and Then Delete File

Tags: rcurl

I am using RCurl for a project. I need to delete a file from a specific directory on the remote server. My issue, in short, is that I can log in successfully, then traverse to the directory in question. But the handle doesn't retain that location. So when I next set up a second command to delete the file, it can't find it (because I'm in the wrong directory). When I log in, it brings me (naturally) to my home directory.

> What I thought would work would be to:
>
> 1. Create a handle
> 2. curlPerform to 'CWD' to the directory (this works!)
> 3. do another curlPerform to delete the file. But the directory is not retained
>    between the two curlPerform commands.

```
  h <- RCurl::getCurlHandle()
```

> In the below, 'unpwd' is a username:pwd pair:

```
  RCurl::curlSetOpt(.opts = list(verbose = TRUE,
                                 userpwd = unpwd),
                    curl = h)
```

> In the below code, 'x' is a string variable.
> URL lists the root directory (when I tried to further specify my homedir
> there, it bombs out. When I omit the home directory, it puts me there automatically, so then the
> directory traversal works. This took a lot of time to figure out!

```
  RCurl::curlPerform(
    url = "ftp://<URL>",
    curl = h,
    quote = paste0("CWD ChangeTo/", x, "/ThisDirectory/")
  )
```

> I'm good to here. It successfully lists the files. So now I try
> the following code. 'filenames' is a vector of the files contained in
> that directory (successfully obtained that in earlier code):

```
  RCurl::curlPerform(url = paste0("<URL>/ChangeTo/", x, "/ThisDirectory/"),
              curl = h,
              quote = paste0("DELE ", filenames[1]))
```

> But here it gives a 550 error: I am once again in my home directory so
> the file is not found there. My 'place' on the server is not retained.

> The curl tutorial (URL: https://curl.se/docs/manual.html) states the following,
> which might explain the problem. In discussing multiple downloads, it states (in
> reference to downloads):
> Note that curl cannot use persistent connections for transfers that are used in subsequent curl
> invokes. Try to stuff as many URLs as possible on the same command line if they are using
> the same host, as that will make the transfers faster. If you use an HTTP proxy for file
> transfers, practically all transfers will be persistent.

> If I try something like the following, I don't cwd into the correct directory,
> either (again, stuck in my home directory):

```
    RCurl::curlPerform(
      url = paste0("<URL>/~/ChangeTo/", x, "/ThisDirectory/"),
      curl = h,
      quote = paste0("DELE ", filenames[1])
  )
```

So, I need to 'cwd' first, then somehow retain that location (it's not embedded in   the handle) and then delete the file.

Worst case scenario, I can delete the files manually at the end using FileZilla, I   guess. But so far as I know there is no proxy server on the remote server, nor can I install one.

Any and all thoughts greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!!